# Model returning null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my code for my model

```
public class ManufacturerModel
{
    public int ProductTYpeId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> manf { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code in cshtml file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addmanufacturer", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formPageID" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <label>Select Existing Manufacturer<span style="color: Red">*</span>:</label>
        <div class="formRight">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id", Model.manf)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Manufacturer Name<span style="color: Red">*</span>:</label>
        <div class="formRight">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.manufacturer.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.manufacturer.name)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I am posting this form and when I am trying to fetch the value from the manfacurer ie -       ManufacturerModel manufacturer = new ManufacturerModel();
using a model object all the value are coming out null.

in the text box If I replace it with m => m.Name then I am able to get proper value of Name.
can any one suggest what the problem is

I am using the manf to bind a dropdown. If In case I post back the form and the if it is return the value becomes blank, I need to refill the value..

```
    public ActionResult addmanufacturer(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            id = "0";

        ManufacturerModel manufacturer = new ManufacturerModel();
        manufacturer.ProductTYpeId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        manufacturer.manf = GetManf();
        manufacturer.Id = -1;

        return View(manufacturer);
    }
```

Comment: please add 1 or all versions of action method u have tried

Comment: from your question, you have 2 name properties - one on your model and another on the manufacturer - which do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use the one in manufacturer model. the other Name was only for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem will be becouse of:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod, HTML ATTRIBUTES )) { }
```

You probably want this overload:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", Route Values, FormMethod, html attributes )) { }
```

Important is say him that you want route values and not a html atrributes, so try this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addmanufacturer", "Admin", new { id = "formPageID" }, FormMethod.Post, null )) { }
```

Hope, it helps.

M.